# Transparency for imported STL files

Tags: materials, texturing

I've created some STL files and can successfully import them into Blender.  The shapes I've created overlap in a meaningful way (think partially overlapping spheres, but more complicated), and I'd like to make them translucent so you can see how the overlaps happen.

I thought the following would work, but it doesn't:

1. Select one of the objects.
2. Go to the materials panel and select the 'Transparency' box.
3. Change the 'Alpha' setting to something less than 1.

At this point the material preview shows a translucent sphere, but my object doesn't change at all.

What gives?  Am I missing some small step that activates the material?  Do I need to have other, opaque objects in my scene in order to observe the transparency?  (Currently I've only loaded these STL objects and nothing else is in the scene.)

This seems like a very simple question and I'm sorry if it's a duplicate.  Ultimately I'd like to make the materials for these objects glass-like to end up with a nice visualization of the following geometry:  http://www.unf.edu/~ddreibel/research/milnor/milnor.html

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does the transparency not change in the render or only in the viewport? Because the viewport only shows transparency when you are in textured view, and for simple materials without texture only with GLSL shading.

Comment: Of course.  Just needed to render and everything looks great.  Thanks!

Comment: @maddin45 can you add your comment as an answer ?